# formatting output in python with specifier not working

Tags: python, format

```
print 'there are %d vowels and they are %s' % 2,'oo'
```

Why isn't this working? the error is about string formatting not enough arguments. I don't really understand....Plz help~

Comment: print 'there are %d vowels and they are %s' % (2,'oo')

Answer (score 3):

You need an iterable to supply formatting options:

```
print 'there are %d vowels and they are %s' % (2,'oo')
```